# delayed_job rails gem error on heroku, maybe bootstrap related?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, twitter-bootstrap, delayed-job

For some reason, simply installing the gem delayed_job_active_record causes my heroku app to crash.

I've run the following steps:
Added to gem file:

```
gem "delayed_job_active_record"
```

Terminal:

```
bundle install
rails generate delayed_job:active_record
rake db:migrate
git add .
git commit -m "added delayed_job gem"
git push
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Everything installs without an error, but then when I load the page, my heroku logs show the following:

```
WARN: tilt autoloading 'sass' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'sass' suggested.
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= yield :head %>
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)):
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:1
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1465ms
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Load path: /app
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1868084818636776228_47102160'
2012-07-07T19:47:14+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
```

When I uninstall the gem, the program goes back to having no errors.  I also don't have any problems if I run on localhost.  The error happens only when I load the delayed_job gem (even if I do nothing else aside from install it)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone in the future that would like to know...this solved it:

Add the following to application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: Found this as I'm getting the same warning. This was already in my application.rb, and so does not solve it (or at least, does not in my case)